# Kruskal's algorithm and disjoint-set data structure: Do I need the following two lines of code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, disjoint-sets, kruskals-algorithm

I've implemented Kruskal's algorithm in C++ using the disjoint-set data structure according to Wikipedia like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#define MAX_EDGES 10000000
#define MAX_VERTICES 200001
using namespace std;
int num_edges,num_vertices;
int total_cost=0;

struct edge{
    int v1,v2;
    int cost;
};

struct comp{
    bool operator()(const edge& e1,const edge& e2){
        return e1.cost<e2.cost;
    }
};

edge edges[MAX_EDGES];
int parent[MAX_VERTICES];
int rank[MAX_VERTICES];

int findset(int x){
    if(x!=parent[x]){
        parent[x]=findset(parent[x]);
    }
    return parent[x];
}

void merge(int x,int y){
    int px=findset(x),py=findset(y);
    if(rank[px]>rank[py]){
        parent[py]=px;
    }else{
        parent[px]=py;
    }
    if(rank[px]==rank[py]){
        ++rank[py];
    }
}

int main(){
    FILE* in=fopen("input","r");
    FILE* out=fopen("output","w");
    fscanf(in,"%d %d\n",&num_vertices,&num_edges);
    for(int i=1;i<=num_vertices;++i){
        parent[i]=i;
        rank[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num_edges;++i){
        fscanf(in,"%d %d %d\n",&edges[i].v1,&edges[i].v2,&edges[i].cost);
    }
    sort(edges,edges+num_edges,comp());
    for(int i=0;i<num_edges;++i){
        int s1=findset(edges[i].v1),s2=findset(edges[i].v2);
        if(s1!=s2){
            merge(s1,s2);
            total_cost+=edges[i].cost;
        }
    }
    fprintf(out,"%d\n",total_cost);
}
```

My question is: Do I need these two lines of code? If so, what's their importance?

1. `int px=findset(x),py=findset(y);`
   in merge instead of `int px=parent[x],py=parent[y];`
2. `parent[x]=findset(parent[x]);` in
   findset instead of `return
   findset(parent[x]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `findset(x)` returns the canonical representative of the set that x is in (the root of its ancestry tree). You need this to be able to compare whether two elements are in the same set or not (they have the same representative), `parent[x]` just returns the parent of x in the tree, which may not be the root.

1a) You forgot to test for px and py being identical in `merge`.

2) It's an optimization so that future calls to `findset` will run faster. If `parent[x]` used to point to its parent which pointed to the root of its set's tree, after this call `parent[x]` will point directly to the root.

Comment: The classes representatives, however, have been stored in s1 and s2, therefore there is (probably) no need to call findset again. In addition, according to http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=disjointDataStructure, there is no need to check if px and py are identical.

Comment: If you don't check that they're not identical, you can end up increasing the rank by one for no good reason -- this can mess up the union-by-rank heuristic down the road...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need this to because `x.parent` is not necessarily the representative of the class to which `x` belongs, so the algorithm wouldn't be correct without it.
2. Without the assignment, the algorithm would be suboptimal. This is the [path compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) optimization, also discussed in the Wikipedia.

Comment: The classes representatives, however, have been stored in s1 and s2, therefore there is (probably) no need to call findset again.

Comment: @Alexandros: I hadn't seen that. I would stick to the usual formulation of disjoint sets and remove the `findset` calls from `main`.

Comment: @Alexandros: Skip the `int s1=findset(edges[i].v1), s2=findset(edges[i].v2);` and call `merge` on `edges[i].v1` and `v2` directly. You may also skip the `findset` in `merge`, but the former option is idiomatic and safer.

Comment: @larsmans: This way, however, I will not know which edges should be added to the MST.